# Connecting SQL Server in Azure (PaaS) using SSMS through my company's VPN

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server (PaaS) in Azure using SSMS installed in my computer and I am connected to my company's VPN.

Port 1433 is allowed on the firewall. However I am getting blocked because a random port number 2579/2573/... and it seems that this port number changes.

Does anyone know which range, besides port 1433, I need to allow on my firewall to get this connection done.

Thanks in advance;

Sorry any english mistakes. English is not my first language.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's trying to connect to a port besides 1433? What makes you think other ports on the server are involved?

Comment: I can see the firewall blocking port 2579. Few weeks ago I saw port 2573...

Comment: @mason I forgot to say that I am using a private link to connect to the sql database, but I don't think that this make any difference.

Comment: Please see it here:  https://ibb.co/J3cStNQ

Comment: Why do you think you're getting blocked? Because of the ping attempts? You didn't specify what port to ping on, so it would use the default port which is probably blocked. That doesn't mean your connection to SQL Server would be blocked. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql) for how to check connectivity.